# Photoelasticity and existence of stress

Tags: stress-strain

Shall we consider photoelasticity a non-mathematical, or purely visual, proof of the existence of stresses in mechanical structures undergoing external loading?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? The theory matches the experiments.

Comment: @fffred It looks to me that the existence of stresses in classical (continuum) mechanics stems from various assumptions/principles at a macroscopic scale (continuity, Newton's laws...) while in physics, at a microscopic scale, the notion of stress is replaced by atomic forces acting between particles. It looks to me that photoelasticity is, in a sense, a visual bridge between these two separate worlds. It somehow illustrates how continuum mechanics can be seen as a homogenized version of the physics of particles.